# WordPress get_template_part() breaking advanced custom forms repeater

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm building a page in WordPress which uses two Advanced Custom Forms repeaters and inserts a template part into the page in between them. If the get_template_part() call is after both repeater all the content loads fine but when it's in between the two repeaters the content after the get_template_part() does not load and I'm not sure why.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="clearfix" role="main" >

        <?php if(get_field('landing')):?>
            <?php while (have_rows('landing') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <section class="block row" id="landing" style="background-image: url('<?php the_sub_field('background'); ?>');">
                        <div class="text-center">

                            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" />                              
                            <p class=""><?php echo the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                            <a class="" href="<?php the_sub_field('section_url');?>"><?php the_sub_field('url_text'); ?></a>
                            <a href="#" class="text-center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/more_icon.png"></img></a>
                        </div>
                </section> <!-- end article header -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_template_part ('social');?>


        <?php if(get_field('section')):?>
            <?php while (have_rows('section') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <section class="block row" style="background-image: url('<?php the_sub_field('background'); ?>');">
                        <div class="text-center">

                            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" />                              

                            <p class=""><?php echo the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                            <a class="" href="<?php the_sub_field('section_url');?>"><?php the_sub_field('url_text'); ?></a>
                            <a href="#" class="text-center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/more_icon.png"></img></a>
                        </div>
                </section> <!-- end article header -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>



</div> <!-- end #content -->
```

Here is the code for the get_template_part() call:

```
<div class="row block">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3>Instagram</h3>
    <p>This is an instagram feed</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3>On The Radio</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h3>In The News</h3>
    <p><?php
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );

        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="pull-right" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><br />
        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></a>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="text-center"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/reclamation_road.png"/></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
        Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an 
        unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
        book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap</p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because in your template part social, you're using `setup_postdata()`, which overrides the current `$post`.

So you have to reset `$post` to the original one. To do that, after the `endforeach`, you should call `wp_reset_postdata()`. For more information and example usage, you can refer to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

Comment: Glad it worked. Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful for you.